# How to change the permissions on a CD-R in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, compact-disc, user-profiles

I have an old Windows XP box with an unprivileged user who nonetheless needs to create backups to a CD-R.  It appears that this is not allowed under the default privileges.  Is there a way to enable just this privilege without also granting administrator (i.e., software installation) privileges?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need to make a couple of settings in Group Policy.

Run gpedit.msc. The location you want is

Local Computer Policy | Computer Configuration | Windows Settings | Security Settings | Local Policies Security Options

Set "Devices: Restrict CD-ROM access to locally logged-on user only" to Enabled

Set "Devices: Allowed to format and eject removable media" to Administrators and Interactive Users

This answer directly copied from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540662(v=vs.85).aspx